# Mysql: Perform of NOT EXISTS. Is it possible to improve perfomance?

Tags: mysql, performance, not-exists

I have two tables **posts** and **comments**. Table **comments** have **post_id** attribute. I need to get all  **posts** with type "open", for which there are no **comments** with type "good" and created date MAY 1.

Is it optimal to use such SQL-query:

```
SELECT  posts.* FROM  posts  
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT comments.id FROM comments WHERE comments.post_id = posts.id 
AND  comments.comment_type = 'good' AND 
comments.created_at BETWEEN '2010-05-01 00:00:00' AND '2010-05-01 23:59:59')
```

I'm not sure that NOT EXISTS is perfect construction in this situation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are right - you can do better. See [this article](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) by [Quassnoi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55159/quassnoi) for the details but the conclusion is:

> That’s why the best way to search for missing values in MySQL is using a LEFT JOIN / IS NULL or NOT IN rather than NOT EXISTS.

Your query rewritten using `NOT IN` could look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts  
WHERE posts.id NOT IN (SELECT post_id
                       FROM comments
                       WHERE comments.comment_type = 'good'
                       AND comments.created_at BETWEEN '2010-05-01 00:00:00'
                                                   AND '2010-05-01 23:59:59')
```

Answer (score 1):

No idea whether it is faster, you could check it out:

```
SELECT * FROM posts
LEFT JOIN comments 
ON comment.postid = post.id
AND comment.comment_type='good'
WHERE comment.postid IS NULL
```

Assuming postid is never NULL / a non NULLable column.