# Query to load results faster after matching with another table wether records exist or not

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `video` and there is another table called `watch_video`. The video table has all the video URLs with the user ids who posted those videos and `watch_video` has the user_ids who watched those videos. Now in order to show unique videos to my users, not the repeated ones I see if the user_id and video_id don't exist in the watch_video table and then show the results But this slows the overall result. Is there any better way to handle it?

```sql
SELECT *
FROM video AS `Video`
WHERE not exists (
    SELECT id
    FROM video_watch as VideoWatch
    WHERE `Video`.`id` = `VideoWatch`.`video_id`
      AND `VideoWatch`.`user_id` =$user_id
)
ORDER BY rand() ASC
LIMIT 10
```

If I don't compare it with the `VideoWatch` Table then records load faster.

Comment: Don't you miss to filter by the user id in the subquery ?

Comment: Do you have indexes on columns needed? Also, share `EXPLAIN` results of the query.

Comment: @AymDev Yeah. I just updated the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysql: Perform of NOT EXISTS. Is it possible to improve perfomance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993332/mysql-perform-of-not-exists-is-it-possible-to-improve-perfomance)

Comment: It seems like using a LEFT JOIN will have better performances.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables, plus `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` so we can see if you have appropriate indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I tried `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE .. IS NULL` on a different pair of tables; it seems significantly faster.

Still `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10` does not optimize well; it necessitates a full scan of `video`.

Here are some alternatives for speeding up "random 10":  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random